# Back menu to return from webview to app

Tags: java, android

I have an Webview which opens when i click on the actionbar item.
So i have Credits and Help, and when i click back it closes the app. Now, i want it not to close the app, but to get back to main screen (like app is launched)
Here's my main activity

```
package com.CPTeam.VselCalc;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.Menu;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuInflater;
import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

import crakeron.vsel.calctest.R;



import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Spinner;
import android.widget.Toast;

    public class VselcalculatortestActivity extends SherlockActivity {
private EditText freqbox1;
private EditText freqbox2;
private EditText freqbox3;
private EditText freqbox4;
private EditText freqbox5;
private EditText voltbox1;
private EditText voltbox2;
private EditText voltbox3;
private EditText voltbox4;
private EditText voltbox5;
private Spinner spinner;

public int freq1;
public int freq2;
public int freq3;
public int freq4;
public int freq5;
public int volt1;
public int volt2;
public int volt3;
public int volt4;
public int volt5;

public boolean stop=false;
public boolean freq4ornot=false;
public boolean freq5ornot=false;

//public String path;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */

private AutoUpdateApk aua;  
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    aua = new AutoUpdateApk(getApplicationContext()); 

    ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    //could be used to modify actionbar if needed





    ChangeLog cl = new ChangeLog(this);
    if (cl.firstRun())
        cl.getLogDialog().show();

    //cl.getFullLogDialog().show(); for testing 

    freqbox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.freq1);
    freqbox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.freq2);
    freqbox3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.freq3);
    freqbox4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.freq4);
    freqbox5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.freq5);
    voltbox1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volt1);
    voltbox2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volt2);
    voltbox3 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volt3);
    voltbox4 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volt4);
    voltbox5 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.volt5);

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,
    R.array.spinner_choices, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    // Specify the layout to use when the list of choices appears
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    // Apply the adapter to the spinner
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener(){
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView <?> adapter, View v, int pos, long lng) {
                    if (pos==0){
                        freq4ornot=false;
                        freq5ornot=false;
                        hide_row4();
                        hide_row5();
                        }
                    if (pos==1){
                        freq4ornot=true;
                        freq5ornot=false;
                        show_row4();
                        hide_row5();
                        }   
                    if (pos==2){
                        freq4ornot=true;
                        freq5ornot=true;
                        show_row4();
                        show_row5();
                        }
                }

                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView <?> arg0) {
                    //nothing FTM
                }
    });
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    MenuInflater inflater = getSupportMenuInflater();
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);   
    return true;
}



public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
    case R.id.Changelog:
        new ChangeLog(this).getFullLogDialog().show();;
        return true;

    case R.id.Help:
        WebView webview = new WebView(this);
         setContentView(webview);
         webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/help.html");  
    return true;

    case R.id.Credits:
        WebView webview1 = new WebView(this);
     setContentView(webview1);
    webview1.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/credits.html"); 
        return true;


    }
    return true;
}






public void show_row4(){
    freqbox4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.textView8).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.TextView03).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    voltbox4.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.d("VselCalc", "Showing row 4");

}

public void hide_row4(){
    freqbox4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.textView8).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.TextView03).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    voltbox4.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.d("VselCalc", "Hiding row 4");
}
public void show_row5(){
    freqbox5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.textView9).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.TextView04).setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    voltbox5.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    Log.d("VselCalc", "Showing row 5");

}

public void hide_row5(){
    freqbox5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.textView9).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    findViewById(R.id.TextView04).setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    voltbox5.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    Log.d("VselCalc", "Hiding row 5");
}

public void button_pressed(View button) { 
    voltbox1.setText("");
    voltbox2.setText("");
    voltbox3.setText("");
    voltbox4.setText("");
    voltbox5.setText("");
    stop=false;
    // 1. Grab values in textboxes freq1,2,3 (and 4 and 5, depending on Spinner value?) and store their values
    grab_values(freq4ornot, freq5ornot);
    // 2. Call calculate function with 3 (or 5) arguments
    calculate(freq1, freq2, freq3, freq4, freq4ornot, freq5ornot);
    // 3. call function to display each result in correct box, if stop=true, then all boxes will be displayed empty
    display_volt(freq4ornot, freq5ornot);
    if(stop==true) error_empty();
}

public void grab_values(boolean freq4ornot, boolean freq5ornot){
    String freq1Value = freqbox1.getText().toString();//fetch what's in edittextbox and store it in a string
    if(freq1Value.length()!=0){
        freq1 = Integer.parseInt(freq1Value);//transform the string into an int and store it in our variable
        }
    if(freq1Value.length()==0){
        stop=true;
        freq1=0;
        }

    String freq2Value = freqbox2.getText().toString();
    if(freq2Value.length()!=0){
        freq2 = Integer.parseInt(freq2Value);//transform the string into an int and store it in our variable
        }
        if(freq2Value.length()==0){//check if user entered a value in box, otherwise causes crash
        stop=true;                      
        freq2=0;
        }

    String freq3Value = freqbox3.getText().toString();
    if(freq3Value.length()!=0){
        freq3 = Integer.parseInt(freq3Value);
        }
        if(freq3Value.length()==0){
            stop=true;                      
            freq3=0;
        }

    if (freq4ornot==true){
        String freq4Value = freqbox4.getText().toString();
        if(freq4Value.length()!=0){
            freq4 = Integer.parseInt(freq4Value);
            }
            if(freq4Value.length()==0){
                stop=true;                                  
                freq4=0;
            }
    if (freq5ornot==true){
        String freq5Value = freqbox5.getText().toString();
        if(freq5Value.length()!=0){
            freq5 = Integer.parseInt(freq5Value);
            }
            if(freq5Value.length()==0){
                stop=true;                                  
                freq5=0;
            }

    }}

}

public void calculate(int freq1,int freq2, int freq3, int freq4, boolean freq4ornot, boolean freq5ornot){
    volt1 = formula(freq1);
    volt2 = formula(freq2);
    volt3 = formula(freq3);
    if (freq4ornot==true){volt4 = formula(freq4);}
    if (freq5ornot==true){volt5 = formula(freq5);}
}


public int formula(int freq){
    int volt = ((freq/20)+2);
    return volt;
}


public void display_volt (boolean freq4ornot,boolean freq5ornot){
    if(stop==false){
        voltbox1.setText(String.valueOf(volt1));
        voltbox2.setText(String.valueOf(volt2));
        voltbox3.setText(String.valueOf(volt3));
        if(freq4ornot==true){voltbox4.setText(String.valueOf(volt4));}
        if(freq5ornot==true){voltbox5.setText(String.valueOf(volt5));}
    }

}


public void error_empty(){
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Please enter a frequency in all the boxes", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    /* For debug purposes
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"stop bool is " + stop, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();*/
}








                    //AUTODETECTION FUNCTIONS!!!

private int detected_freq1;
private int detected_freq2;
private int detected_freq3;
private int detected_freq4;
private int detected_freq5;
private String path;

public void auto_detect(View button){
    stop=false;
    freq4ornot=false;
    freq5ornot=false;
    //get the path string (for multiple device support) that leads to the cpu_freq file
        {get_path();}       
    //read and process the file specified by path() and extract the frequencies         
        detect();       
    //fill the 4/5 freq boxes with the frequencies found
        write_freq(detected_freq1,detected_freq2,detected_freq3,detected_freq4,detected_freq5);

        if (stop==true){error_device();}
    }

    private void get_path(){
        //find path for frequencies available
        // for Defy (and milestone, and many other android devices) it is /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies
        // for multiple devices support, probably store the paths in a table in the future          
        path="/sys/devices/system/cpu/cpu0/cpufreq/scaling_available_frequencies";

        //for testing, put a file called "Test" in the root directory of your phone to test behavior on 4/5 freqs
        //path="/Test";
    }

    private void detect(){
        String[] segs;
        FileReader fstream;
        long Read;

        try {fstream = new FileReader(path);
        Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "Opened '" + path + "' file correctly");
        } 
        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {               
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Could not read " + path, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            stop=true;
            return;
        }

        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(fstream, 500);
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {

                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "line read:"+  line);
                    segs = line.trim().split(" ");
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "segs length: " + segs.length);

                    Read = Long.parseLong(segs[0]);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "Auto-Detect freq. Read1: " + Read);  
                    detected_freq1= (int) Read/1000;

                    Read = Long.parseLong(segs[1]);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "Auto-Detect freq. Read2: " + Read);
                    detected_freq2= (int) Read/1000;

                    Read = Long.parseLong(segs[2]);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "Auto-Detect freq. Read3: " + Read);
                    detected_freq3= (int) Read/1000;

                    hide_row4();
                    hide_row5();
                    spinner.setSelection(0);

                    if(segs.length>=4){
                    Read = Long.parseLong(segs[3]);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "Freq4 exists. Auto-Detect freq. Read4: " + Read);
                    detected_freq4= (int) Read/1000;
                    freq4ornot=true;
                    spinner.setSelection(1);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "freq4ornot changed to true after auto-detect");
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "freq5 or not: " + freq5ornot);
                    show_row4();
                    hide_row5();
                    }

                    if(segs.length>=5){
                    Read = Long.parseLong(segs[4]);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "Freq5 exists. Auto-Detect freq. Read5: " + Read);
                    detected_freq5= (int) Read/1000;
                    freq5ornot=true;
                    spinner.setSelection(2);
                    Log.d("VselCalc_AutoD", "freq5ornot changed to true after auto-detect");
                    show_row4();
                    show_row5();
                    }


            }               
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e("readfile", e.toString());
        }
        return ;
    }                       

    public void write_freq(int fr1, int fr2, int fr3, int fr4, int fr5 ){
        if(stop==false){
            freqbox1.setText(String.valueOf(fr1));
            freqbox2.setText(String.valueOf(fr2));
            freqbox3.setText(String.valueOf(fr3));
            if(freq4ornot==true){freqbox4.setText(String.valueOf(fr4));}
            if(freq5ornot==true){freqbox5.setText(String.valueOf(fr5));}
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Auto-Detection successful!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }           
    }

    public void error_device(){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Function may not be supported on your device. Please contact the developers", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
```

}

I haven't added webview to layout/main.xml because it opens when i click on required actionbar item.

```
case R.id.Help:
    WebView webview = new WebView(this);
     setContentView(webview);
     webview.loadUrl("file:///android_res/raw/help.html");  
return true;
```

Targeted Android Version is 4.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should override `onBackPressed()` in your activity class.

```
public void onBackPressed ()
```

> Since: API Level 5 Called when the activity has detected the user's
>   press of the back key. The default implementation simply finishes the
>   current activity, but you can override this to do whatever you want.

Copy this code in your activity, and do whatever you want in it.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //this is where you start your activity
    }
```

Comment: How? What to write?
Can you be more detailed?

Comment: I did that before..but i want to return to app. not to close it. I tried various solutions but always got FC!
I edited question with piece of code where my webview is.

Comment: "Default back press closes the current activity." When you override this method, back press will no longer close your app. It will react as what you wrote in this method.

Comment: Yeah..but i want it to go to default menu (when i started the app), not to remain in webview

Comment: I will be more clear: If you want backpress to start an activity, you must write it in onBackPressed() method. write "startActivity(your Intent)" in this method.

Comment: Ok, that partially worked...but i don't want users to not be able to exit the app...whenever i click the back button it restarts activity, but i want it limited only to those 2 actionbar options...how?

Comment: Default backpress returns to the activity before the current one where it left working, so if you are using any "finish()" in your code, it will kill your current activity so you cannot go back to it where it left working. Other than this, i have no idea what closes your application when you pressed back. If you don't want to restart your activity, you should delete "startActivity" and write "super.onBackPressed" method in override.

Comment: Ok, i explained wrongly. I need users to be able to close the app when they are at home menu and restart activity when they are in credits or help menu

Answer (score 1):

When back button is pressed the current intent/ activity is closed and returned to the previous intent/activity in the stack. Here You are creating a webview and just setting that as the content of your **current activity**. So when you press back, the activity is closed, which in turn closes the application as you don't have any previous intent/activity. Instead override onBackPressed and in there setContentView as main layout.

```
@Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            setContentView(R.layout.main);
            //Do other functions you want to do here  
    }
```

Comment: I already did that, but i cant exit the app in main menu..it keeps restarting the activity

Comment: You want to restart the activity or return to previous page (R.layout.main), what is it you want?

Comment: I want to return to r.layout.main BUT ONLY from those 2 webivews. My app is not all webview..it has alot of buttons, spinners menus..and i added webview for help and credits

Comment: I will tell you a simple solution. Make a flag true when those 2 webviews are loaded/set as content of activity. And on back pressed check whether that flag is true or not. If flag is true use setcontentview(R.layout.main) else super.onBackPressed();

Declare the flag as global